# State field in Civicrm profile display as digit

Tags: civicrm

I'm using D7, with CiviCRM 4.4.6. I had use civicrm to create a profile, for user to enter and edit their billing address in their account.

The country, displaying well as "Malaysia", but the state field is displaying as digit, "07".

Is there any way that I can display the state name, just like the selected name in drop down when editing state field?

Comment: Go to: Administer => Localization => Langauge, Currency, Locations (civicrm/admin/setting/localization?reset=1) and check to make sure that Malaysia is included in the State/Province settings.

Comment: Yes, I had added in, but it is still displaying as digit. Is there any method I can display the name instead of abbreviation?

Comment: @vences please add your vote to the [CiviCRM SE site petition](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77367/civicrm?referrer=8gfMpihOSETXeNHrjdyxXQ2) so we can have a dedicated space for these questions.

Comment: If you haven't already done so, it would be great to see you supporting the proposal for a new CiviCRM StackExchange site: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77367/civicrm?referrer=sZxmfwEWAHDXeNHrjdyxXQ2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the table:

civicrm_state_province

specifically the column abbreviation for malaysia. If i had to guess, all the abbreviations are numeric and hence u r seeing numbers.

You can use PHPMyAdmin to find the relevant rows for malaysia. Your short term fix will be to populate the right values. Would be even better for you to submit a PR against civi-core so that changes get incorporated into future versions

Answer (score 2):

'Administer > Localization > Address Settings' provide display format in terms of token, that we see on Contact Summary page's Address Section, not for profile usage.

Profile is being composed of fields, so when we view/edit a profile those field(s) got displayed in freezed or desired HTML element format respectively.

As in your case it seems like there is a js break involved, because last time I encountered such problem for a drop-down where name(label) is being replaced by integer(value).

Do you have firebug installed to see if there is any error report on console, which might help us to dig further!

Comment: If you folks haven't already done so, it would be great to see you supporting the proposal for the new CiviCRM StackExchange site: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77367/civicrm?referrer=sZxmfwEWAHDXeNHrjdyxXQ2

Answer (score 1):

I have found that by default CiviCRM displays a code or an abbreviation for state/province rather than the full name.

You can change this by going to Administer > Localization > Address Settings (siteroot/civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/address?reset=1)

Here you can see the tokens that are used for mailing labels and for address display. Edit the token that reads "{contact.state_province}", changing it to "{contact.state_province_name}". Then the addresses should display using the full name of the state/province as stored in the database.

Comment: I tried it, but it shows empty field...

Comment: It did shows the name, but in contact summary page, not in my account page profile part